# Ошибка после обновления WP в Gutenber "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

Tags: php, wordpress, gutenberg

Не первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, когда после обновления **core wordpress** перестаёт работать редактор Gutenberg, в консоле и на странице выводит ошибку *"Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."*. Научите справляться с этой ошибкой, куда смотреть, чтобы её понять? На время установил плагин **Disable Gutenberg**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

QueryMonitor во вкладке HTTP API Calls пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас REST не работает. Отключите дурацкие плагины оптимизации.

Comment: @KAGGDesign плгины оптимизации отключены. Где можно найти отключение REST?

Comment: Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную, всё будет работать. Так найдёте тот плагин/тему что отключает REST в целях псевдооптимизации.

Comment: @KAGGDesign разбираюсь, спасибо за наводку

Comment: Несколько раз с таким сталкивался, в стандартных темах такая же беда была, пересохранение permalinks помогало.

Comment: @Simon пробовал - не помогло

Comment: @KAGGDesign привет. Поменял тему, с новой темой работает и плагины те же включены. После переключения сохраняются страницы, но ошибку пишет. В console network ошибок не выдаёт. Что это может быть?